# Is there anything wrong with asInstanceOf in this example using generics?

Tags: scala, generics

Consider this (somewhat contrived) example:

```
abstract class Obj[A, B] {
    def id: Long
    def parent: B
}

abstract class TopLevel[A] extends Obj[A, A] {
    def parent: A = this.asInstanceOf[A] // How terrible is this?
}

abstract class AbsChild[A, B] extends Obj[A, B] {
    def parent: B
}

case class Top(id: Long) extends TopLevel[Top]

case class Child(id: Long, parent: Top) extends AbsChild[Child, Top]
```

To paint a better picture, imagine `AbsChild` as some kind of directory on a file system, and `TopLevel` as the physical drive that an `AbsChild` belongs to. So `parent` doesn't actually refer to the direct parent of the object (like the directory that contains it), but rather a reference to the top level object in the tree.

In some applications, I'm going to be dealing with a `List[Obj[A, B]]`, where it isn't immediately known what `Obj` is. In this case, it would be nice for even a `TopLevel` to have a `parent`, which should just return a reference to itself. And herein lies my question.

Defining `def parent: A = this` for `TopLevel` doesn't work:

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : TopLevel.this.type (with underlying type TopLevel[A])
 required: A
```

But `def parent: A = this.asInstanceOf[A]` does, and *seems* to function correctly in practice.

```
scala> val top = Top(1)
top: Top = Top(1)

scala> val child = Child(1, top)
child: Child = Child(1,Top(1))

scala> top.parent
res0: Top = Top(1)

scala> child.parent
res1: Top = Top(1)
```

But is this really okay? Using `asInstanceOf[A]` feels incredibly dirty, and leaves me wondering if it will fail somehow with a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would get a `ClassCastException` if you had a subclass of `TopLevel[A]` that wasn't an `A`. To avoid the need to cast you should use a self type (I'm not sure if that's the correct name):

```
abstract class TopLevel[A] extends Obj[A, A] {
  this: A =>
    def parent: A = this
}
```